# Where i can find a good guide or tutorial to debug multithread delphi applications?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

i'am looking for tips ,a guide or tutorial to debug  multithread delphi applications.

where can find such info?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this year's CodeRage, Boian Mitov of Mitov Software gave an excellent lecture on multi-threading in Delphi. It includes tips and tricks and things to watch out for.   Although this isn't directly a "how to debug" tutorial, it discusses common problems, and approaches he recommends and why.

http://www.embarcadero.com/coderage5/sessions: Technical Session #44, on Thursday. (Best to download the MP4 and play it full screen so you can read all the text in the IDE. His accent is a bit strong, but he's totally understandable. )

(I use Mitov's real-time video library (VideoLab for Delphi and .NET) and his plotting and signal labs in a commercial product. They make heavy use of threads, are extremely fast and very reliable. This guy knows what he's doing, IMO.)

Answer (score 2):

If your application is not yet written, consider using a framework dedicated to multi-threading.

Take a look at http://otl.17slon.com

Using such high-level units will make your debugging much easier, because it provides you with a lot of dedicated classes and methods, which will handle most of the multi-thread problems for you.

Sometimes, refactoring could be much more productive than debugging a badly designed application.